# jQuery get many objects with same class and switch between them

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to grab many objects with same class in jQuery and then show previous object with same class by clicking prev button and next one by next btn? I'm just starting with programming and try to write recipies store and I stucked on that, I can grab value of element I click on but don't know how to switch between them using buttons

```
<div>
    <button class="prev"></button>
    <button class="next"></button>
    <p class="showRecipies"></p>
    <ul>
        <li class="recipies">Drinks</li>
        <li class="recipies">Vegetables</li>
        <li class="recipies">Meet</li>
        <li class="recipies">Fruits</li>
        <li class="recipies">Others</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery to grab value of recipie I clicked on

```
$(".recipies").on("click", function () {
        var recipieValue = $(this).text();
        var showRecipies = document.querySelector(".showRecipies");

        showRecipies.innerHTML = recipieValue;
    })
```

UPDATED:

it works but let me ask one more question:) and thank you for your help so far! I decided to a bit improve my code to make it easier to style and update and I decided that every recipie will be separate ul, to make it easier to read etc

```
<div>
    <button class="prev"></button>
    <button class="next"></button>
    <p class="showRecipies"></p>
    <ul class="listOfRecipies">
      <li>
        <ul class="particularRecipie">
          <li class "timeOfPreparation>3:20</li>
          <li class="recipies">Drinks</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
         <li class "timeOfPreparation>3:20</li>
         <li class="recipies">Vegetables</li>
      <li>
        <ul class="particularRecipie">
         <li class "timeOfPreparation>3:20</li>
         <li class="recipies">Meet</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      <li>
         <ul class="particularRecipie">
          <li class "timeOfPreparation>3:20</li>
          <li class="recipies">Fruits</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="particularRecipie">
         <li class "timeOfPreparation>3:20</li>
         <li class="recipies">Others</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</div>
```

In this case I should just go higher through parent() property right? Like:

```
$(".recipies").on("click", function() {
  $(".recipies.active").add($(this)).toggleClass("active");
  var recipieValue = $(this).text();
  var showRecipies = document.querySelector(".showRecipies");

  showRecipies.innerHTML = recipieValue;
});

$(".next").click(function() {
  var isLast = $(".recipies.active").is(":last-child");
  var $this = $(".recipies.active") || $(".recipies:first");
  if(isLast){
    $this.parent().parent().find(".recipies:first").trigger("click");
  } else {
    $this.next().trigger("click");
  }
});

$(".prev").click(function() {
  var isFirst = $(".recipies.active").is(":first-child");
  var $this = $(".recipies.active") || $(".recipies:first");
  if(isFirst){
    $this.parent().parent().find(".recipies:last").trigger("click");
  } else {
    $this.prev().trigger("click");
  }
});
```

Comment: on your click just check if there is any value or not in the `.showRecipies` if yes then add the `.showRecipies` value to `.prev` and replace the new value on `.showRecipies`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
  var isLast = $(".recipies.active").is(":last-child");
  if(isLast){
    $(this).parent().find(".recipies:first").trigger("click");
  } else {
    $(".recipies.active").next().trigger("click");
  }
});

$(".prev").click(function() {
  var isFirst = $(".recipies.active").is(":first-child");
  if(isFirst){
    $(this).parent().find(".recipies:last").trigger("click");
  } else {
    $(".recipies.active").prev().trigger("click");
  }
});
```

I've added `$(".recipies.active").add($(this)).toggleClass("active");` to your `.recipies` click function, so we know what `li` is active/has been clicked

**Demo**

```js
$(".recipies").on("click", function() {
  $(".recipies.active").add($(this)).toggleClass("active");
  var recipieValue = $(this).text();
  var showRecipies = document.querySelector(".showRecipies");

  showRecipies.innerHTML = recipieValue;
});

$(".next").click(function() {
  var isLast = $(".recipies.active").is(":last-child");
  var $this = $(".recipies.active") || $(".recipies:first");
  if(isLast){
    $this.parent().find(".recipies:first").trigger("click");
  } else {
    $this.next().trigger("click");
  }
});

$(".prev").click(function() {
  var isFirst = $(".recipies.active").is(":first-child");
  var $this = $(".recipies.active") || $(".recipies:first");
  if(isFirst){
    $this.parent().find(".recipies:last").trigger("click");
  } else {
    $this.prev().trigger("click");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <button class="next">next</button>
  <p class="showRecipies"></p>
  <ul>
    <li class="recipies">Drinks</li>
    <li class="recipies">Vegetables</li>
    <li class="recipies">Meet</li>
    <li class="recipies">Fruits</li>
    <li class="recipies">Others</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `prev()` and `next()` to cycle through the available recipies:

```js
var rec = $('.recipies:first');
$('.showRecipies').html(rec.html());

$('.prev').click(function() {
  rec = rec.prev('.recipies');
  
  if (!rec.length) {
    rec = $('.recipies:last');
  }
  
  $('.showRecipies').html(rec.html());
});

$('.next').click(function() {
  rec = rec.next('.recipies');
  
  if (!rec.length) {
    rec = $('.recipies:first');
  }
  
  $('.showRecipies').html(rec.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <button class="next">next</button>
  <p class="showRecipies"></p>

  <ul>
    <li class="recipies">Drinks</li>
    <li class="recipies">Vegetables</li>
    <li class="recipies">Meet</li>
    <li class="recipies">Fruits</li>
    <li class="recipies">Others</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Next button:**

```
$(".next").click(function () {
    let currentRecipies = $('.recipies.current');
  let currentRecipiesValue = $('.recipies.current').text();
  let currentRecipiesIndex = $('.recipies.current').index();
  let nextRecipiesIndex = currentRecipiesIndex + 1;
  let nextRecipies = $('.recipies').eq(nextRecipiesIndex);
  currentRecipies.removeClass('current');
  let showRecipies = document.querySelector(".showRecipies");

  if (nextRecipiesIndex == ($('.recipies:last').index()+1)) {
    $('.recipies').eq(0).addClass('current');
    showRecipies.innerHTML = currentRecipiesValue

  } else {
    nextRecipies.addClass('current');
    showRecipies.innerHTML = currentRecipiesValue
  }
})
```

**Prev:**

```
$(".prev").click(function () {
    let currentRecipies = $('.recipies.current');
  let currentRecipiesValue = $('.recipies.current').text();
  let currentRecipiesIndex = $('.recipies.current').index();
  let nextRecipiesIndex = currentRecipiesIndex - 1;
  let nextRecipies = $('.recipies').eq(nextRecipiesIndex);
  currentRecipies.removeClass('current');
  let showRecipies = document.querySelector(".showRecipies");

  if (nextRecipiesIndex == ($('.recipies:first').index() - 1)) {
    $('.recipies').eq(4).addClass('current');
    showRecipies.innerHTML = currentRecipiesValue

  } else {
    nextRecipies.addClass('current');
    showRecipies.innerHTML = currentRecipiesValue
  }
})
```